# Electron: socket.io can receive but not emit

Tags: node.js, socket.io, electron

I'm creating an Electron application that uses Socket.io to communicate to a server application, but I'm experiencing a weird issue: whereas my Electron app successfully joins and receives messages from my server, it completely fails to emit anything.

**Client-side:**

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
// ...
var socket = io("http://localhost:8081");

socket.on('welcome', () => {
  console.log('welcome received'); // displayed
  socket.emit('test')
});
socket.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(e); // not displayed
});
socket.on('ok', () => {
  console.log("OK received"); // not displayed
});
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log("connected"); // displayed
  socket.emit('test');
});
```

**Server-side:**

```
io.on('connection', (client) => {
  io.emit('welcome');

  client.on("test", () => {
      console.log("received test"); // not displayed
      io.emit("ok");
  })
});
io.listen(8081);
```

Note that there is also a Web client that connects to the server, and works absolutely as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your socket.io code is working in electron Environment, I am also having the same case My socket is working well with web with express but not with electron

Comment: I could not find any solution to this problem, so I finally got rid of this and used a (dirty) workaround based on a REST API… :(

Comment: What type of error is throwing in client console  provide ur code both server and client with git or. Here so that I can reproduce it

Comment: I'm sorry, I had this issue months agos, and I do not have access to the app code anymore since I do not work in the company where I coded that anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Electron has the main process that can have node integration and renderer process that has [`nodeIntegration`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) turned off by default for security reasons.

If you try to use your client code in the main process (main.js) it will work and receive/emit normal. But if you try to use the client code on the rendered process, then it won't work. You need to add the client code inside the `preload.js` and then preload it using the [`webPreferences.preload`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) option of the `BrowserWindow` like this:

```js
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
  ...
}
```

Then you can have the client code inside `preload.js`:

```js
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io(`http://localhost:${process.env.SOCKET_PORT}`);

socket.on('welcome', () => {
  console.log('on welcome : welcome received renderer'); // displayed
  socket.emit('test')
});
socket.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(e); // displayed ?
});
socket.on('ok', () => {
  console.log("OK received renderer"); // displayed
});
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log("connected renderer"); // displayed
  socket.emit('test');
});
```

begin the socket, start the electron app and see it working:

#### Socket server:

[image: socket.io server]

#### App console:

[image: Electron app]

Beware of the [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP):

[image: Content Security Policy error]

To avoid this, you have to add your WS server to your CSP. For localhost use this inside `index.html` header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' ws://localhost:*/socket.io/; script-src 'self' ws://localhost:*/socket.io/">
<meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' ws://localhost:*/socket.io/; script-src 'self' ws://localhost:*/socket.io/">
```

It's a localhost server for all ports and of course it's for development only, you have to enter normal WS server in production.

You can clone and check my working example from Github: https://github.com/clytras/electron-sockets

**EDIT**
Last but not least; check and allow incomming/outgoing access for nodejs and/or port in firewal.

```
Electron version: 7.1.2
Node version: 12.8.1
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I had some important details in with the bounty i put on this question, but admin deleted it... god knows why. So if you could have a look at the same issue here with the details added, it would be greatly appreciated!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973435/electron-renderer-process-websocket-issue-bounty-for-the-solution

Comment: @lamisti I commented out on your original question. Please share the electron version you're using.