# Socket.IO and Electron can't emit or receive

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, electron, vue-cli

I have an `Electron` project initiated with `VueCLI` and a litle nodejs `socket.io` server, here's the server's file :

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const {
  userJoin,
  getCurrentUser,
  userLeave,
  getRoomUsers,
  users
} = require('./utils/users');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

// Set static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Run when client connects
io.on('connection', socket => {

  console.log(`Connected tp ${socket.id}`)
  app.get('/send-file', (req, res, next) => {
      res.send('Sent')
  })

  socket.on('joinRoom', (args)=>{
    console.log('joinroom')
  })


  // Runs when client disconnects
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    const user = userLeave(socket.id);
  });
});



const PORT = process.env.PORT || 7575;

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

And here's my `preload.js` file :

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
window.socket = io('http://localhost:7575');

window.socket.on('welcome', () => {
    console.log('on welcome : welcome received renderer'); // displayed
    window.socket.emit('test')
});
window.socket.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(e); // displayed ?
});
window.socket.on('ok', () => {
    console.log("OK received renderer"); // displayed
});
window.socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log("connected renderer"); // displayed
    window.socket.emit('test');
});
```

And here's my `createWindow` function:

```
async function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 700,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
      // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration for more info
      nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })
  win.setMenu(null)
  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    await win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools()
  } else {
    createProtocol('app')
    // Load the index.html when not in development
    win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
  }
}
```

The connection is made between the client and the server, because the `console.log(`Connected tp ${socket.id}`)` show a different **socket ID** everytime, but on my compenent, when I call the `emit` function nothing happens : `window.socket.emit('joinRoom', {email:this.email, apikey:this.apikey})`

And I can't event receive message on the client side, I've tested the server and everything works fine on a normale browser, but on my electron application can't `emit` or receive messages.

Is this related to my electron application?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it -

Server side:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// middlewares
app.use(express.static('public'))

// routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
})

server = app.listen(7575, () => {
    console.log("Server started");
})

//socket.io instantiation
const io = require("socket.io")(server)

//listen on every connection
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('New user connected');

    //listen on "test"
    socket.on('test', (data) => {
        var username = data.username;
    })
})
```

Client side:

```
socket = io.connect('http://localhost:7575')
socket.emit('test', {username: 'username'})
```

Comment: But does it work within the Electron app? I found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384902/electron-socket-io-can-receive-but-not-emit that it's not so straightforward.